Une médaille au creux de la main. Is this a French expression?
From a book I'm translating for myself. The full sentence is:

J'ai déjà pleuré, une médaille au creux de la main.


I had already cried, a medal in the palm of my hand.

Makes no sense to me. Is this perhaps a French expression?

Not a set phrase, it probably has to be taken literally but since you are not giving any context it is difficult to tell. Book ? Title  ? Author ? Context ? A mere search in a search engine shows the sentence quoted several time in relation to dogs and the book seems to be Son odeur après la pluie by  Cédric Sapin-Defour. This book is about  the loving relationship of the author with his dog. So I would not be surprised the medal to be a dog medal.  After the death of his dog the narrator cries, holding the medal in his hand.

Just to complement @None's comment: déjà is a sure sign we are missing part of the context. Depending on it, the translation might be I had cried before, a medal in the palm of my hand.

J'ai déjà pleuré, une médaille au creux de la main. is I have already cried, a medal in the crook of my hand. creux is crook, not palm... In English, you need a comma.

What makes the most sense, perhaps, is that the speaker is holding the lost dog's tag, his identification tag, in his hand. In Reverso, the three top French translations of "dog tag" are étiquette de chien,médaille, and plaque d'identité.
On Amazon France, a paw-shaped name tag is listed as "médaille chien." [https://amzn.eu/d/eFW5vRh][1] Under the product description: "La médaille est livrée avec deux anneaux métalliques pour une fixation facile au collier de votre animal."

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Yes, dog tag, not medal. Good catch.

No, une médaille au creux de la main is not a set expression although creux de la main1 is a common collocation. It means exactly that. The person tells what happened to them: they cried with a medal in their hand and perhaps it's happening again as they speak.
The context should make clear why they cried and what it has to do with the medal.
@None in comments states:

A mere search in a search engine shows the sentence quoted several time in relation to dogs and the book seems to be Son odeur après la pluie by Cédric Sapin-Defour. This book is about the loving relationship of the author with his dog. So I would not be surprised the medal to be a dog medal. After the death of his dog the narrator cries, holding the medal in his hand.

1 The creux de la main is the central part of the hand, especially but not necessarily when it is partially or totally closed. It translates to the hollow of the hand.

It is indeed from "Son Odeur...." , which I am reading and occasionally getting stuck on. The passage deals with the death of the author's previous dog and his reaction. This is my amateur translation:      "Since then, his absence has followed me every day and nothing has been at all normal except that life goes on. So I knew. Just what an emotional undertaking it would be. I have already cried a medal in the palm of the hand. To take on a dog is to take on an unfading love, you never separate,......"
